# This contact form PHP code is sending the email through but all that is coming up is "From:" with nothing else after it?

Tags: php

This is a PHP code that I have been struggling with for a while. This code sends out the email that a user would click the submit button and the message goes to the set email address. What I am struggling with is every time I try to send the info through, it goes through, but I cannot get anything to come up but "From:" and that's it, none of the information goes through its just blank. I have been looking at YouTube and asking questions to other web programmers and nothing has worked so far so I am wondering anybody can help me on here.

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$to = "daileyproductions@gmail.com";
$subject = "New Message";

mail ($to, $subject, "From: " . $name . $email . $phone . $message);
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried outputting the values of `$name`, `$email`, etc.? Maybe their value isn't quite what you think.

Comment: What does your form look like? Do all your inputs have matching `name=...` attributes?

Comment: Yes they do.name, email, phone, and message all match.

Comment: `<form method="post"` ???

Comment: `This contact form`, ***what form?*** Provide your code.

Comment: ObSecurity - Please use a mail-sending library, such as Swiftmailer. There are many things that can be done wrong and will open your code up to security issues. A well-developed library can avoid many of the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. It works on my system.

I would guess that you're passing an empty request. Try replacing `$_POST` with actual text and see what you get. In case you get the right message you should take a look at how you're processing `$_POST` data (and yes, it's better to escape user input).

In case your `$_POST` data collected correctly, then I would suggest using  [**PHPMailer**](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) - it's easier and straight forward.

---

Additional points:

1. You may need to add correct end of line characters to the Headers. It may be `\n` or `\r\n`;
2. Run `phpinfo()` and check for `sendmail_path`;
3. Check your mail server's mail log, usually in `/var/log/maillog` to debug the problem. It could easily be your *MTA*.